# How to loop to create separate PD dataframes in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am in Python using Pandas for this manipulation. 
The shape of my data is (1488000, 10).

I need to create a loop that will groupBy each separate category in the 3rd column, WORKLOAD_NAME , and create its own separate DF. The 3rd column has about 66 categories and so **I need 66 respectively named and separate DFs as a result from this loop.**

Here is what the data looks like:

[image]

**HERE IS WHAT I WANT FOR EACH SEPARATE DF-- separated DFs by WORKLOAD_NAME:**

[image]

**Please note:**

1) I did this for 1 single df, but this would be unsatisfactory to do it manually 65 more times:

```
EDWARDLOAD_WL = data[data.WORKLOAD_NAME == 'EDWARDLOAD']
```

2) I created a set of the unique names of the categories and then tried to create a loop like this:
[image]

```
for i in workload_set:
    [i]_WL = data[data.WORKLOAD_NAME == i ]
```

but it didnt do anything for me. Any thoughts?

3) Lasly, I tried this .groupBY():

```
data_grouped = tuple(data.groupBy('WORKLOAD_NAME'))
data_grouped.head()
```

But it didn't work either-- "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'groupBy'"

Comment: it's `.groupby`, no capital B. Also likely just `data_grouped = data.groupby('WORKLOAD_NAME')`

Comment: Also why do you need 66 different `DataFrames`? That seems like a real nuisance and the real problem may be more easily solved with a single list, or just a grouped object.

Comment: We are created entirely separate analyses and systems for each workload so it makes sense to separate them all at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to save separate files to excel:

```
names = df['WORKLOAD_NAME'].unique()
for n in names:
    df[df['WORKLOAD_NAME']==n].to_excel(n+'.xlsx')
```